# My try exept not working outside the function

Tags: python, error-handling

i was catching error if error occurs then implement the except code. but it is not executing except code

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"]

#TODO: Catch the exception and make sure the code runs without crashing.

try:
    def make_pie(index):
        fruit = fruits[index]
        print(fruit + " pie")
except:
    print("Fruit pie")

make_pie(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to catch an exception when the function is *defined*, rather than when it is *called*.

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"]

def make_pie(index):
    fruit = fruits[index]
    print(fruit + " pie")

try:
    make_pie(4)
except KeyError:
    print("Fruit pie")
```

Or, you want the `try` statement *inside* the function.

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"]

def make_pie(index):
    try:
        fruit = fruits[index]
    except KeyError:
        fruit = "Fruit"

    print(fruit + " pie")

make_pie(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are only using try on defining the function, you must try catch inside the function.

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"]

def make_pie(index):
    try:
        fruit = fruits[index]
        print(fruit + " pie")
    except:
        print("Fruit pie")

make_pie(4)
```